# R How do I add a dataframe column whose values are derived from other column values in a DIFFERENT row?

Tags: r

The answer to this question might be simple but I can't seem to get around it.

I have a dataset with: years, treatments, treatment levels and a value (yield). Treatments include mineral (fertiliser), manure and compost. I would like to add a column with a reference value. This reference should be the value (yield) of given year and level of the mineral treatment. For example:

```
DF1<-data.frame(treatment = c("mineral","mineral", "manure","manure","compost","compost","mineral","mineral", "manure","manure", "compost","compost"),
            year = c("1990","1990","1990","1990","1990","1990", "1991","1991","1991", "1991","1991","1991"),
            level = c("1","2","1","2","1","2","1","2","1","2","1","2"),
            value = c("1","2","1.1","2.2","1.3","2.5","3","4","3.2","4.4","3.5","4.8"))

DF1
 treatment year level value
mineral 1990     1     1
mineral 1990     2     2
 manure 1990     1   1.1
 manure 1990     2   2.2
compost 1990     1   1.3
compost 1990     2   2.5
mineral 1991     1     3
mineral 1991     2     4
 manure 1991     1   3.2
 manure 1991     2   4.4
compost 1991     1   3.5
compost 1991     2   4.8
```

Mineral should be the referent. So I would like to add a column called ref which will give for all treatments (manure, compost and mineral) in year 1990 a value 1 if level 1 and a value 2 if level 2. For the year 1991 the reference value should be for all treatments 3 if level 1 and 4 if level 2.

Anybody would could give me advice on this: I would be very grateful

Comment: Could you show the expected `ref` column

Comment: Okay, then, i must have misunderstood the question.  But, I think this could be solved without a loop.

Comment: Yes I think so too, only have no idea how...

Comment: Anyway, I updated, I guess this time it should work.

Comment: O.k. Thanks! I improved the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
 res <- do.call(rbind,
         lapply(split(DF1, list(DF1$year, DF1$level), drop=TRUE),
                function(x){x$ref <- x$value[x$treatment=='mineral']
                  x}))
 indx <- as.numeric(gsub(".*\\.", "", row.names(res)))
 res1 <- res[order(indx),]
 row.names(res1) <- NULL
 res1
```

Or using `data.table`

```
 library(data.table)
 DT <- as.data.table(DF1)
 DT1 <- DT[treatment=='mineral', list(ref=value), by=list(year, level)]
 DT[,indx:=1:.N]
 setkey(DT, year, level)
 DT[J(DT1)][order(indx),][,indx:=NULL][]
 #    treatment year level value ref
 #1:   mineral 1990     1     1   1
 #2:   mineral 1990     2     2   2
 #3:    manure 1990     1   1.1   1
 #4:    manure 1990     2   2.2   2
 #5:   compost 1990     1   1.3   1
 #6:   compost 1990     2   2.5   2
 #7:   mineral 1991     1     3   3
 #8:   mineral 1991     2     4   4
 #9:    manure 1991     1   3.2   3
#10:    manure 1991     2   4.4   4
#11:   compost 1991     1   3.5   3
#12:   compost 1991     2   4.8   4
```

Comment: Thanks for thinking along. This suggestion works well for this small example dataset, but is more accidental I think (still nice idea) but I have a set with hundreds of data points, with many different years, treatments and levels, so I would like to find a way to redirect to the value of a mineral treatment in a certain year and add that to the ref column. I am now thinking of using the function ave() to group first. Like:

Comment: DF1$ref_minN <- ave(
  DF1$year, DF1$level,  FUNCTION = )

Only that I can't think of a function here which would work. It would need to perform the same as a subset would do (like for a specific group, subset(DF1, treatment == "mineral", select = value)), but ave() needs a real function and doesn't allow a subset here...

Comment: Sorry for not being more clear in my initial question, it seems more difficult to explain than I thought. The ref column by Akrun is correct in this example but wouldn't work on a large dataset

Comment: Reponse to update: The reference is not necessarily the minimum value (only that's the case coincidentally in this example), it should be the value at treatment mineral in given year and level. A colleague of mine gave me the answer in loop-form, I will post it here